# Unable to go back to previous (sensor) activity after playing video

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am just new in Android Programming. I am having trouble on my app. This app uses sensor, and when it hits a certain treshold. It will open another activity and play video. Sensor activity is actually working and it plays the video when it hits the treshold. My problem is: when the video finishes, it crashes and logcat says

> < E/AndroidRuntime(4418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause
>   activity {...}: java.lang.NullPointerException.

I want my app to go back to the main activity which is the sensor activity after it plays the video.

Hope you can help me out. Thanks.

Below is the snippet of my manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hahndroid.myapp.SensorActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hahndroid.myapp.PlayVideoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

below is the snippet of my 1st activity which is a sensor activity and it works fine:

package com.hahndroid.myapp;

```
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

        private SensorManager mySensorManager;

// some variables and computations

    }

private void executeShakeAction() {

    Intent Intent = new Intent(this, PlayVideoActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(Intent, 0);

         // it plays the Video from raw folder of PlayVideoActivity.class 
}
```

below is the java code of the 2nd activity which I named PlayVideoActivity.class:

package com.hahndroid.myapp;

...

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView videoView;
    Intent intent;
    MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp=null;
        }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
    }  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);


        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview); 
        Uri pathToVideo = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.hahndroid.myapp/" + R.raw.mp4_file`enter code here`);  
        videoView.setVideoURI(pathToVideo);
        videoView.requestFocus(); 
        videoView.start();


        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();

        }
        });

    }

}
```

Below is the Logcat logs:

> 03-12 16:47:54.809: D/AndroidRuntime(4418): Shutting down VM 03-12
>   16:47:54.809: W/dalvikvm(4418): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210) 03-12 16:47:54.819:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-12 16:47:54.819:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4418): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause
>   activity
>   {com.hahndroid.creepyguard/com.hahndroid.myapp.PlayVideoActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-12 16:47:54.819:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4418):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>   03-12 16:47:54.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682)
>   03-12 16:47:54.819: E/AndroidRuntime(4418):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2660)

I tried to edit my 2nd activity (PlayVideoActivity) like this:

package com.hahndroid.myapp;

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mp;
VideoView videoView;
Intent intent;



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
    }


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp=null;
}  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);


    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview); 
    Uri pathToVideo = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.hahndroid.myapp/" + R.raw.mp4_file`enter code here`);  
    videoView.setVideoURI(pathToVideo);
    videoView.requestFocus(); 
    videoView.start();


    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

    }
    });

}
```

}

But still having the same error in logcat, Eclipse having trouble pausing the activity...

so I tried removing that onPause() and onDestroy,, what happened was: after playing the video on that 2nd activity it returns to the 1st activity(sensor activity) but looks like it stuck, it didn't sense anymore, however, the error in logcat gone... but I know it is still wrong...

My app activities should run back-and-fourth (1st activity should sense a certain threshold then will play the video then after playing the video, it should go back to 1st activity and sense again).

Please help me generate the correct code. thanks again in advance.

Hahn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not providing a full stack trace. The stack trace continues to reveal the underlying cause, which is `mp` being null in `onPause()`; you've never assigned a value to the variable. (Note that it is also referenced in `onDestroy()`.)

If you had (correctly) specified `mp` to be `private`, Eclipse would have warned you about this. It would also have been revealed to you if you ran your code in debug mode, as the debugger would stop on the line with the uncaught exception.

Comment: thanks for the answer I will edit my app as you said, and I will get back to you with the result.

Comment: I am still "googling" those terms as I am very new in programming :). Again, thanks. And hope you guys can extend your patience.